# Limiting the number of visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've created Q&A section that consists of several boxes vertically stacked on top of each other. I found out that if I were to open all of the boxes, the page wouldn't fit, so I was wondering if I could use JavaScript of jQuery to limit the amount of `active` boxes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faqOuter").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('faqOuter-change');
    $(this).parent().find('.faqInner').slideToggle(500, 'swing');

    if ($(this).parent().height() == 75) {
      $(this).parent().animate({
        height: '225'
      }), 500, 'swing';
    } else {
      $(this).parent().animate({
        height: '75'
      }), 600, 'swing';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="faqSection">
  <div class="faqSectionSub">
    <h4 class="faqOuter">Trial One Bar</h4>
    <div class="faqInner">
      <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil expetendis in mei.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faqSectionSub">
    <h4 class="faqOuter">Trial One Bar</h4>
    <div class="faqInner">
      <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil expetendis in mei.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="faqSectionSub">
    <h4 class="faqOuter">Trial One Bar</h4>
    <div class="faqInner">
      <p>Alienum phaedrum torquatos nec eu, vis detraxit periculis ex, nihil expetendis in mei.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

[image: Image for Reference]

Is there a way to only display one box at a time?

Comment: "the page wouldn't fit" what?

Comment: Sure, just before you open it in script, choose all of the elements with jQuery selector and close them

Comment: `$(".faqOuter").click(function() { $(".faqInner").slideUp("slow");...`

Comment: @Sébastien Since I won't have anything below the 'Write Us' box, I want to make it so that the Q&A section doesn't stick out too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Accordion from JqueryUI,

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

The collapsible content option would be a better choice for you,
https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

Comment: Thanks dude! I would've never thought of it! Sadly, that means that I'm going to have to do some major restructuring... Rip. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript you have will open then inner divs on click. You just need the following line to hide all the inner boxes. Setting display to none collapses (hides) all the visible divs.

```
  $(".faqInner").css("display","none");
```

Here is what your document.ready function should look like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".faqOuter").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('faqOuter-change');
    $(this).parent().find('.faqInner').slideToggle(500, 'swing');

    if ($(this).parent().height() == 75) {
      $(this).parent().animate({
        height: '225'
      }), 500, 'swing';
    } else {
      $(this).parent().animate({
        height: '75'
      }), 600, 'swing';
    }
  });
  $(".faqInner").css("display","none");
});
```

Comment: Just like to point a few things out. The code you just entered, is not inside the function, so it won't have much of an effect. If you were to put it in front of the code, it doesn't exactly work as intended. Once the 'faqInner' box is opened, if you try to click it's parent div, it won't close. That's because your line of code would hide the box, and the subsequent  line would toggle it open. Bear in mind, simply toggling the display 'faqInner' won't do much, as the height of the parent div has also changed. Hence I'll need to hide the 'faqInner' box, and change its parent's height.